# What messaging pattern should I use to process and return responses from a rest request?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, vert.x

I have a hub and spoke architecture similar to this:

[image]

where a GET request comes into the hub and it routes it to one of the spokes for processing.  On the hub I also put the request in a map with a UUID so that I can return the proper response when I get the data back from processing. The spokes are identical and are used to balance the load.  I then need to pass the information back to the hub from the spoke and return the proper reponse.
I would like to do the messaging using JMS.

What is the best combination of [integration patterns](http://camel.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have Request/Reply within Vert.x, so you can achieve this behavior with about 20 lines of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    router.get("/").handler((request) -> {
        // When hub receives request, it dispatches it to one of the Spokes
        String requestUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        vertx.eventBus().send("processMessage", requestUUID, (spokeResponse) -> {
            if (spokeResponse.succeeded()) {
                request.response().end("Request " + requestUUID + ":" + spokeResponse.result().body().toString());
            }
            // Handle errors
        });
    });

    // We create two Spokes
    vertx.deployVerticle(new SpokeVerticle());
    vertx.deployVerticle(new SpokeVerticle());

    // This is your Hub
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8888);
}
```

And here's what Spoke looks like:

```
/**
 * Static only for the sake of example
 */
static class SpokeVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    private String id;

    @Override
    public void start() {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        vertx.eventBus().consumer("processMessage", (request) -> {
            // Do something smart

            // Reply
            request.reply("I'm Spoke " + id + " and my reply is 42");
        });
    }
}
```

Try accessing it in your browser on http://localhost:8888/

You should see that request ID is generated every time, while only one of two Spokes answers your request.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Well if I understand your design correctly this seems to request/reply scenario since the spoke is actually returning some response. If it didn't it would be publish/subscribe.

You can use ActiveMQ for jms and request/reply. See here:
http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html

As for the details it all depends on your requirements, will the response be sent fairly immediately or is it a long running process?

If it is a long running process you can avoid request/reply and use a fire and forget scenario.

Basically, the hub fires a message on a queue which is being listened by one of the spoke components. Once the backend processing is done it returns the response to a queue monitored by the hub. You can correlate the request/response via some correlationId. During the request part, you can save the correlationId in a cache to match against the response. In a request/reply scenario this is done for you by the infrastructure but don't use for long running process.

To summarise:
Use ActiveMQ for your message processing with JMS.
Use Camel for the REST bits.
Use request/reply if you are sure you expect a response fairly rapidly.
Use fire and forget if you expect the response to take a long time but have to match the message correlationIds.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use Camel with JMS, then you should use [Request-Reply EIP](https://camel.apache.org/request-reply.html), and as far as examples go, you have a [pretty good one provided via Camel's official examples](https://camel.apache.org/tutorial-jmsremoting.html) - it may be a bit old but it's still very much valid.

While you can just ignore the example's Camel configuration through Spring, its route definitions provide sufficient information:

```
public class SpokeRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("jms:queue:spoke")
            .process(e -> {
               Object result = ...; // do some processing
               e.getIn().setBody(result); // publish the result
        // Camel will automatically reply if it finds a ReplyTo and CorrelationId headers
            });
    }
}
```

Then all HUB needs to do is invoke:

```
ProducerTemplate camelTemplate = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
Object response = camelTemplate.sendBody("jms:queue:spoke", ExchangePattern.InOut, input);
```